# Drive angular npm build using the Visual Studio Configuration

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-template

Using Visual Studio 2017 with the latest Angular Template, is there a way to drive the "npm build -- --[environment]" command based on the configuration that Visual Studio is set too (Development, Test, QA, Release)?

I can see when I do a publish (no matter the configuration) Visual Studio is executing the "npm build -- --prod" command, this is not very useful as I need to deploy to a Test and QA environment as well.

I am aware of how to open a command prompt and manually executing the command, I wish to eliminate this step from the process.